# Sizing objects based on screen dimensions

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Given different screen sizes what is the accepted method of scaling the UI?

In setting up a UI it looks great on one screen but terrible on another. Trying to set up a possibly dynamic style based on screen dimensions. I have here a simple header with a FormattedString in a label.  I want to center the entire label with the spans formatting remaining intact. Ideally I'd like to set the height of the text to some percentage of the Current.MainPage.Height ...

**From App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderSpans" TargetType="Span" >
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 20, 0, 0"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderSpan" TargetType="Span" >
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"></Setter>

        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="HeaderSpanB" TargetType="Span" >
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Code behind**

```
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                //MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                //MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case Device.UWP:
                //MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Orange;
                break;
            default:
                //MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
                break;
        }
```

I thought that I might be able to utilize this code to do the deed.  But I don't know how to impact the styles from there. I thought that a setter might be the right path. I have not made solid progress.

**From Header.xaml**

```
<!-- dark-blue backing header -->
<Image Source="Header752x135.png" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Image>

<!-- SHIPSHAPE text placed on the backing header -->
<Label

    Style="{StaticResource HeaderSpans}"
>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="SHIP" Style="{StaticResource HeaderSpan}" />
            <Span Text="SHAPE" Style="{StaticResource HeaderSpanB}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

With no code behind.

I would be appreciative if anyone could lead me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change values of your UI depending on the platform, you could make use of the "On Platform" Statement.
For instance, if you want to have a different margin for a grid on iOS than you need to use on Android, you could use it like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Margin>
        <On Platform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS">0,0,0,0</On>
            <On Platform="Android">15,0,15,0</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Grid.Margin>
</Grid>
```

Of course you can use that for other properties as well. Keep in mind that if you set a property in your view.xaml it will override the style definition of the same property if present.

Making your font size dependent on the screen height can be done as follows:

**Getting the screen dimensions - Shared**

We will need to implement a dependency service, which allows us to retrieve the actual screen height or width.

Therefore in the shared code, create a new interface:

***IScreenDimensions.cs***

```
public interface IScreenDimensions
{
    double GetScreenWidth();
    double GetScreenHeight();
}
```

in your android implementation, add the implementation of the interface:

**Getting the screen dimensions - Android**

***ScreenDimensions.cs***

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ScreenDimensions))]
namespace MyAppNamespace.Droid
{
    public class ScreenDimensions : IScreenDimensions
    {
        public double GetScreenHeight()
        {
            return ((double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / (double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        }

        public double GetScreenWidth()
        {
            return ((double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / (double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        }
    }
}
```

**Getting the screen dimensions - iOS**

***ScreenDimensions.cs***

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ScreenDimensions))]
namespace MyAppNamespace.iOS
{
    public class ScreenDimensions : IScreenDimensions
    {
        public double GetScreenHeight()
        {
            return (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
        }

        public double GetScreenWidth()
        {
            return (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

**Building a value converter to consume the screen dimensions**

Now we create an IValueConverter (again in shared code):

***ScreenSizeToRelativeSizeConverter.cs***

```
public class ScreenSizeToRelativeSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double height = DependencyService.Get<IScreenDimensions>().GetScreenHeight();
        return (double) height * (double) parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // no need to convert anything back
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that the converter needs a parameter that will tell it which fraction of the screen size the resulting size will end up with.

**Putting it all together**

Finally you add the following resources to your App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:ScreenSizeToRelativeSizeConverter x:Key="SizeToRelativeSizeConverter"/>
        <x:Double x:Key="fontSizeFactor">0.03</x:Double>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SizeToRelativeSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource fontSizeFactor}}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And set the style to your label (or other element) in question:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Comment: I thought that the On platform was deprecated? Is this just the code behind OnPlatform and not the xaml side On Platform? At any rate I will be trying what you have here I will let you know what the outcome is. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, OnPlatform is kind of depracated. On Platform (notice the space) is the replacement. Don't ask me why though, I don't get it either.

Comment: Ultimately this answered my question. Thank you. I learned a lot about the power of the setters.  I need to formulate a better question that does not lead to a possible solution. I think I may not be thinking about the problem properly and there may be an answer that I am too close to the forest to see the trees as they say.