# Is there a way that I can determine the display size and use this to adjust the height of a font with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I set the size of a font like this:

```
<Style x:Key="DetailLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="35" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="35" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How could I for example change this iOS font size to 20 if I found the mobile application being used was a phone with a smaller display area height?

I read before that Xamarin had some nuget package that could help me with this.  Has anyone come across this?

Comment: I have answered a similar question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845998/sizing-objects-based-on-screen-dimensions/52849388#52849388

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sizing objects based on screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845998/sizing-objects-based-on-screen-dimensions)