# DynamicResource styling of listview and grid row heights in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grid-layout, dynamicresource

I'm using dynamic resources to set the font size of my UI elements so that on a small tablet the text is a little bigger to be easier to read, but smaller on the very small screen device I also need to support. Works great.

What doesn't work great is scaling the rows containing that text. For example (edited for brevity):

Resource definitions in App.xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Int32 x:Key="Std32RowHeight">50</x:Int32>
        <x:Double x:Key="StdRowHeight">40</x:Double>

        <x:Double x:Key="StdFontSize">20 </x:Double>
        <Style x:Key="ListText" TargetType="Label"  ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource StdFontSize}" />
        </Style>
        ...
```

Xaml code:

```
        <ListView x:Name="locationList"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayGroups}"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="{DynamicResource StdRowHeight}">  <!-- Causes a runtime error -->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="{DynamicResource StdFontSize}"  <!-- Works -->
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

... causes this runtime error:

"Cannot assign property "Height": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property"

I also tried this method:

```
        <ListView x:Name="locationList"
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayGroups}"
            HasUnevenRows="false"
            RowHeight="<DynamicResource Std32RowHeight}"  <!-- This row height is an int32 instead of double... -->
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="{DynamicResource StdFontSize}"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

... which has no effect.

I've read lots of articles/post/examples about styling applications, but they only change the font size or color. (Fantastic example: [Sizing objects based on screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845998/sizing-objects-based-on-screen-dimensions))

If you change the font size, how do you change the row size to match? For extra credit, how would you do it for a grid row? I dabbled in GridLength resources, but couldn't get that to work, either.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your Listview XAML HasUnevenRows is false. Try setting that to True if you want dynamic row heights